# Why my countsort cannot put element in dst[0]?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, count, radix-sort

This is a function of count sort, I write it according to text book and there is something wrong
dst[0] comes a random number while it should have be 0; However, the 0 appears in dst[1] and 2 in dst[2]... finally 8 in dst[9];
Seem like there is a bias, but I donnot know where it is.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

//count sort;
/*arr: pointer to array, ifas: index of start, ifae: index of end, nfs: number of start, nfe: number     of end*/ 
int* countsort(int* arr, int ifas, int ifae, int nfs, int nfe){
    int * ap = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (nfe - nfs + 1)), tmp;
    int * dst = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (ifae - ifas + 1));
    for(tmp = 0; tmp <= nfe - nfs; tmp++){
        ap[tmp] = 0;
    }
    for(tmp = ifas; tmp <= ifae; tmp++){
        ap[arr[tmp] - nfs]++;
    }
    
    for(tmp = 1; tmp <= nfe - nfs; tmp++){
        ap[tmp] += ap[tmp-1];
    }
    for(tmp = 0; tmp <= 9; tmp++){
        printf("%d ", ap[tmp]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(tmp = 0; tmp <= 9; tmp++){
        printf("%d ", arr[tmp]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(tmp = ifae - ifas; tmp >= 0; tmp--){
        dst[ap[arr[tmp] - nfs]] = arr[tmp];
        ap[arr[tmp]-nfs] = ap[arr[tmp]-nfs] - 1;
    }
    for(tmp = 0; tmp <= 9; tmp++){
        printf("%d ", dst[tmp]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(ap);
    return dst;
}

int main(){
    int arr[10] = {9,5,3,8,0,1,6,4,7,2};
    int* res = countsort(arr,0,9,0,9);
}
```

I would appreciate if someone can find the location of the bug.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Readability of code is very important. Especially for beginners. Your formatting (especially indentation) is rather poor. Do yourself and anyone reading your code a favor and apply proper and consistent indentation.

Comment: You may find https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ to be helpful.

Comment: In C you do not need (and you should not) cast the result of `malloc` and similar functions. It is useless in best case and hides errors in worst case. Also you should not use any pointer assigned with result of `malloc` without checking for `NULL` first. Accessing a pointer that holds `NULL` is causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: There's no such thing as `<malloc.h>`. `malloc()` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: You have a loop that prints the `ap` array. What did the output of that loop tell you?

Comment: Firstly, considering I may want to sort some parts of an array, I use index of start/end. Suppose I have arr[20] and I want to sort elements between
arr[4] and arr[10], then index of start is 4 and end is 10; If the element
I want to sort is in interval [10, 100], then number of start is 10 and end
is 100; I am sorry to say it in comment, but I cannot edit! It always reminds me there are codes in desbite of pressing ctrl+k.

Comment: reply to  user3386109: debugger in vscode donnot tell me data in arbitrariness address like gdb, so I use loop to print data

Comment: Replay to ruakh , Barmar and Gerhardh: thank for your advice

Comment: I cannot reply people because I am a green hand in stack overflow

Comment: Hiding `tmp` in `int * ap = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (nfe - nfs + 1)), tmp;` is about the ugliest declaration I have seen for several years. What is wrong with `int tmp;` as a separate line?!

Answer (score 0):

In this loop:

```
    for(tmp = ifae - ifas; tmp >= 0; tmp--){
        dst[ap[arr[tmp] - nfs]] = arr[tmp];
        ap[arr[tmp]-nfs] = ap[arr[tmp]-nfs] - 1;
    }
```

the assignments to `dst` and `ap` are in the wrong order. Compare with the algorithm in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#Pseudocode), it has:

```
    for i = length(input) - 1 down to 0 do
        j = key(input[i])
        count[j] = count[j] - 1
        output[count[j]] = input[i]
```

Your `ap` array corresponds to `count` in the pseudo-code, and you need to decrement the count before assigning to the output, not after. That's why everything is off by 1 in the result.